# How to override the default state parameters in redux reducers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, redux, jestjs

I have something like this. Suppose the following file is `reducers123.js`

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import * as types from './actionTypes';

function reducer1(state = {
    someId: 0,
    someCategory: []
}, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
     'someActionType1' :
          state.someCategory = action.someCategoryData;
          break;
     'someActionType2' :
          state.id = action.someId;
          break;
  }
}


const appReducer = combineReducers({reducer1});
export default appReducer;
```

I'm calling the above reducer in test file as following.

```
import reducers from `./reducers123.js`;

describe('some reducer test case', () => {
    it('test case', () => {
       reducers({someCategory: ['d1', 'd2', 'd3']}, {type: 'someActionType1'});
    });
});
```

So here it should take the `someCategory` data as `['d1', 'd2', 'd3']` but it's taking an empty array [] which I defined initially. I need to override the value of `someCategory` array in my test case. So how to do it. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your reducer is written wrong.  The line `state.someCategory = action.someCategoryData;` is mutating the existing `state` parameter - don't do that!  Instead, you should make a *copy* of the `state` object and overwrite the `someCategoryData` field in the copy.  See the [Immutable Update Patterns](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns) page in the Redux docs for examples.

Second, when you use `combineReducers`, you are saying that you expect this slice reducer to handle the one specific key/slice of the state.  When you run `combineReducers({reducer1})`, you are defining a state shape that is an object with a key of `reducer1` inside of it.  So, your test needs to pass in an object like this:

```
const testState = {
    reducer1 : {
        someId : 123,
        someCategory : ["d1", "d2", "d3"]
    }
}

const result = reducers(testState, {type : "someActionType1"});
// assert that the result is what you expect
```

I'd suggest exporting your `reducer` function separately as a named export so that you can test it by itself, and exporting the combined reducer as a default export.  I'd also suggest reading through the [Using `combineReducers`](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/using-combinereducers) section in the Redux docs.

Comment: Thanks @markerikson. Actually, source code is not mine. I can not export it. I have to find some way to write the unit test case without exporting a reducer.